# How to loop through a joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

The models I have:

**Category:**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :providers, through: :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
end
```

**Provider:**

```
class Provider < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categorizations
end
```

**Categorization:**

```
class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :provider
  has_many :games, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :games
end
```

**Game:**

```
class Game < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :categorization
end
```

I need to display the games, that belongs to a specific provider. I tried to do it like:

```
<% @provider.categorizations.joins(:games).each do |game| %>
 <%= game.title %>
<% end %>
```

It gives me an error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'title' for #<Categorization:0x007f2cf6ee49e8>`. So, it loops through the `Categorization`. What is the best way to loop through the joined `games` table? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should do the request in your controller, or even better call a scope (defined in a model) from the controller.

Do not forget that Active Record is just an ORM, a tool allowing you to manipulate SQL.

With `@provider.categorizations.joins(:games)` you are not asking for games. You are asking for the categorizations and you do a JOIN with the games table. This joins is usually to allow to filter by games attributes.

To do what you want you should do the following :

`@games = Game.joins(:categorization).where('categorization.provider_id = ?',@provider.id)`

As you can see, the join do not return categorization, it allow me to use categorization as a filter.

You should always be aware of the SQL generated by Active Record. Look at the SQL query generated in your server's traces.

Comment: Did as you said: in the controller, I have defined `@games` variable, and after that it gives me an error:  `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "categorization"
LINE 1: ...ations"."id" = "games"."categorization_id" WHERE (categoriza...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "games".* FROM "games" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categorizations"."id" = "games"."categorization_id" WHERE (categorization.provider_id = 2)):`

Comment: Sorry, just had a typo: `categorization.provider_id` should be `categorizations.provider_id`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing 'title' is an attribute of games and not categorization, so you either need to return an array of games, or add a select on the end to pull the title attribute into the categorization object, like so:

```
<% @provider.categorizations.joins(:games).select('dba.games.title').each do |game| %>
  <%= game.title %>
<% end %>
```

Just to add- you shouldn't really be doing this in the view file. I'd go as far as not even doing this in the controller. I tend to encapsulate this sort of logic into a service class, which is instantiated in the controller to return a set of results. The controller should only be passing the result set on, which is then presented by the view.

```
class Provider < ActiveRecrord::Base

    # this could be a scope instead, or in a seperate class which 
    # the provider model delegates to- whatever floats you boat
    def get_games
        # you could use pluck instead, which would return an array of titles
        categorizations.joins(:games).select('dba.games.title')
    end
end 

class ProviderController < ApplicationController
    def show
        provider = Provide.find(params[:id])
        @games = provider.get_games
    end
end

<% @games.each do |game| %>
    <%= game.title %>
<% end %>
```